# Help proving (rigourously) that this double limit exists

Tags: limits, proof-verification

Please note, first I use the following definition for a limit (**not** the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition):

If $D\subset \mathbb{R},$ then $f$ has limit $L$ at $a$ if, given any sequence $(x_n)$ in $D   -\{a\}$  such that $x_n\rightarrow a, f(x_n)\rightarrow L.$

Now, I'm trying to prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}[\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}$].

My proof:
First, the inside limit:

Let $y_n$ be any sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $y_n\rightarrow0.$

Then $f(y_n)=\frac{x^2}{x^2+y_n^2}\rightarrow\frac{x^2}{x^2+0^2}=\frac{x^2}{x^2}=1.$

Now, for the outer limit:
Let $x_n$ be any sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $x_n\rightarrow0.$

Then $f(x_n)=1\rightarrow1$, so the double limit is $1$.

Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct!

One small remark: your computation of the inner limit only works if $x \ne 0$.  If $x = 0$, then $\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{x^2}{x^2 + y^2} = 0$.  But that's okay, because the definition of the outer limit requires that $x_n \ne 0$ for all $n$.